# parsing python flat and nested lists/tuples

Tags: python, list, parsing, tuples

I'm trying to parse a tuple of the form:

```
a=(1,2)
```

or

```
b=((1,2), (3,4)...)
```

where for a's case the code would be:

```
x, y = a
```

and b would be:

```
for element in b:
    x, y = element
```

is there an fast and clean way to accept both forms?  This is in a MIDI receive callback
(x is a pointer to a function to run, and y is intensity data to be passed to a light).

Comment: The right way to do this is to always accept the same level of nesting. So, never `a = (1, 2)`, always `a = [(1, 2),]`. Tarantula is getting downvoted because this doesn't answer your question, but that doesn't change its correctness, albeit it doesn't seem he meant to point that out :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# If your input is in in_seq...
if hasattr(in_seq[0], "__iter__"):
    # b case
else:
    # a case
```

This basically checks to see if the first element of the input sequence is iterable. If it is, then it's your second case (since a tuple is iterable), if it's not, then it's your first case.

If you know for sure that the inputs will be tuples, then you could use this instead:

```
if isinstance(in_seq[0], tuple):
    # b case
else:
    # a case
```

Depending on what you want to do, your handling for the 'a' case could be as simple as bundling the single tuple inside a larger tuple and then calling the same code on it as the 'b' case, e.g...

```
b_case = (a_case,)
```

---

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, a better version might be...

```
from collections import Iterable
if isinstance(in_seq[0], Iterable):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Amber, I can't vote you up because it requires >= 15 reputation. I'm playing with hasattr now...

Comment: It is bad advice to check for `__iter__`. Use `collections.Iterable`.

Comment: It's bad advice to use either.

Comment: What is the reason to use collections?  The data is pretty sanitized by the time I'm parsing it.  Are there any performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do that would be:

```
a = ((1,2),) # note the difference
b = ((1,2), (3,4), ...)

for pointer, intensity in a:
   pass # here you do what you want
```

Comment: I think the question is how to accept `a=(1,2)`, not `a=((1,2),)`.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to pass through functions, 'def fn(val) <CR> return val <CR> returns (1,2) if i pass it (1,2), --- this is my first question, how do a <CR> in this reply without posting?

Comment: @Bill: what you mean by "pass through functions" ?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate a little more on your original question, what did you supposed that a function: 'def fn(val): return val' would return with the parameter '(1,2)' ?